# subdomain name validation in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a signup form where users kan enter their subdomain of choice when creating an account.

```
http://_________.ourapp.com
```

I want them to be able to enter valid characters on the ____________________ part above only. I'm using a text field for that.

Is there a function or some sort of pattern that exists for such situations? Spaces should be filtered, I guess many or all special characters (except numbers, dash and letters) as well?

Comment: Yes. If you post some of your HTML form, you may get examples. Also, it is easier to test for what you want, than what you don't want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use Regular Expressions to achieve what you need.

Try something like this:

```
<input id="username" type="text" onblur="validSubdomain()" />


function validSubdomain() {
    var re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/;
    var val = document.getElementById("username").value;
    if(re.test(val)) {
        alert("invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(subdomainName.match(/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]$/))) {...what to do if valid here...} else {...invalid handling here...}` - I reckon that ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript 1.2 and later supports regular expressions. That's practically every browser these days.

Using your example of "numbers dashes and letters" as being acceptable subdomains, you could do something similar to the following, probably run when the "submit" button on the form is clicked (and if the match fails, then cancel the submission).

```
entry.Match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/)
```

Without more concrete information I really can't give you a full example, but this should get you where you need to go. Of course, keep in mind that javascript validation is not complete for a robust website. You need to re-check this on the server side to protect against people that have javascript disabled (or, in the worst case, malicious users).

Answer (score 0):

For Jquery validation follow this steps

First Add Method of Jquery Rule

```
$.validator.addMethod("subdomainV", function(value, element) { 
      var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*$");
      return regex.test(value);
    }, "Please provide proper subdomain name");
```

Apply this added method to required field

```
subdomain : {
                required: true,
                subdomainV: true /*** New Rule Applied */
          }
```

Answer (score -2):

So your question is, "***What rules do a valid internet domain name follow?***"

The answer to that is:

- it can only contain:

  - the 26 letter of the English alphabet (case-insensitive)
  - numbers (0-9)
  - hyphen/minus sign (-)
- it must start and end with a letter or number, not a hyphen;
- the **labels** must be between 1 and 63 characters long;
- the entire hostname cannot exceed 255 characters

A domain name is comprised of multiple labels, each separated by a period. A direct subdomain of `ourapp.com` would be `ben.ourapp.com`, where `ben`, `ourapp` and `com` are each labels. But you may also optionally allow users to include periods inside of their subdomain, e.g.:

```
ben.franklin.ourapp.com
i.have.a.clever.vho.st
```

In those cases, you could allow the user's child domain to be longer than 63 characters (63 * the number of periods in the child domain, with a max size of 244 (`.ourapp.com` is 11 characters long).

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Internet_hostnames) for more info on valid hostnames.

**Edit:** If you want to support [internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), things get a bit more complex, though still manageable.